# Tomcat 9 Restarts (Possible: Busy Threads)

Tags: memory, java, connection, tomcat

We are currently running Tomcat 9.  I'm not sure our configuration is correct. We are running on CentOS 7 with Quad Core Servers behind a load balancer. Everything seems to work well until a certain volume of users begin accessing it.  Monitoring software alerts us to busy threads and the pages will not render nor can the server be accessed via SSH directly.  Is this possibly an issue with need to reconfigure to have garbage collection optimized?  Our current settings are as follows:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xms4096m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Xmx8192m"
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"
```

Our server.xml has the following for the connector:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="1000" minSpareThreads="80"
               compression="on" 
               compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is insufficient information in the question to enable the root cause of the problems you describe to be identified.

Busy threads and being unresponsive to ssh suggests that the server is running at 100% CPU for an extended period of time. There are many possible causes for this. You need to use a profiler to find out what is using the CPU - ideally in a load test environment rather than production.